# How to print mark highlight in Bootrstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having  a problem printing the Bootstrap's `mark` highlight on my page. I have the following code:

`<mark class='RedHighlightColor'>text...</mark>` .

My CSS is:

```
.RedHighlightColor{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white;
}
```

When I try to print, the `mark` highlight doesn't print.

My CSS print:

```
@media print {

.RedHighlightColor{
        background-color: red !important;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers normally don't print background colors unless you specify it.

To print them with background colors, you got to turn it on. In Google Chrome, check this box:

[image]